# Cucumber.io test scenarios are running in parallel not in sequence

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber, appium, automation-testing

I am using cucumber.io for my Automation Test framework (Java + Selenium + Appium) and we have multiple scenarios and features, and I want to execute all at once. Note, when I run feature by feature it works fine without errors and it runs in random sequence. When I run from IDE (e.g. Intelli J, Visual Studio Code, or Eclipse) tests are running in sequence at a random order and it's all passing. But when I run it from terminal and specify a tag like this

```
-Dcucumber.options="--tags @TagToRun"
```

It execute scenarios from different features in parallel which lead to errors in Appium; most commonly `Error creating a session`. I assume it leads to this error since in my @AfterClass I specify to quit drivers and then quit Appium service. How can I run all scenarios in different features in sequence not in parallel?

Comment: Which version of Cucumber are you using?

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje Cucumber-java-7.10.0

Comment: Then `cucumber.options` doesn't work. Use `cucumber.filter.tags`. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/pull/1741

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like tests were running it parallel, which caused the issue. This was fixed by configuring `maven-surefire-plugin` plugin to run only one test.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
         <parallel>none</parallel>
         <threadCount>1</threadCount>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```